# How to add a button to the navigation menu?

Tags: html, button

I'm trying to add a button to the navigation menu so it is on the right.

Any code snippets would be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need your code snippet to see where to add it.

Comment: I have added some code.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried as well?

Comment: I have tried researching the answer and editing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to *just add it* as the first item in your nav. (See Demo below)

Is there something about this code example that is not what you want? Or is this what you wanted to see?

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('body').append('<div id="msg">Where would you like to go today?</div>');
});

$('body').on('click', '#msg', function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
#msg{position:fixed;top:5vh;left:15vw;padding:1vw;background:wheat;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav">
  <button>Test</button>
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want it on the right side, just place it after the *About* `<a>` tag.

But if you want it on the far right side, with the nav on the far left side, you can do it like this:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('body').append('<div id="msg">Where would you like to go today?</div>');
});

$('body').on('click', '#msg', function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```css
#msg{position:fixed;top:5vh;left:15vw;padding:1vw;background:wheat;}

.flex-parent{display:flex; justify-content:space-between;}
.flex-child{}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-child">
    <button>Test</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>
```

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56604044/1447509